# DRF - Token authentication alongside normal

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I have an internal API where all `ViewSet`s has `LoginRequiredMixin` because this API is used only by logged in users.

Now I need to sometimes make it available through `auth_token` - eg. when the user is not logged in but has a token.

I've added `TokenAuthentication`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
                                'rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter'],

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',


    ],
}
```

And tried to access API using Authorization header: `Token <MYTOKEN>` but it redirects all requests to log in.

How to make it work so the user has to be either authenticated or use an Authorization header?

This is a `ViewSet`:

```
class OrderViewSet(LoginRequiredMixin, ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    filterset_class = OrderFilter
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this problem, i have 2 solution for you

**1.Remove `LoginRequiredMixin`, because `LoginRequiredMixin` used for django View authentication not for django rest framework view (*authentication)**

```
class OrderViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    filterset_class = OrderFilter
```

and then add on `setting.py` file set the default `permission` and `authentication` class of `REST_FRAMEWORK`, like this

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
                            'rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter'],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}
```

**2.if you want to set `permission` and `authentication` add on class view, you do not have to setting.py file config. Try this**

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication

class OrderViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication, )
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    filterset_class = OrderFilter
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include 'rest_framework.authtoken' in your INSTALLED_APPS setting.

---

see here 
[TokenAuthentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication)

Comment: It is included so the problem is not here.